# new Date() using Javascript in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, safari, new-operator

I'm having an issue using the new Date() function in Javascript.  Safari is giving me an "Invalid Date" message.

I've created a short example at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ogesi4/edit).

This appears to work on all other browsers, but not Safari.  Any ideas on how I can take the value from an input (such as 2011-01-03) and turn it into a date object, while having it work properly in Safari?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The date parsing behavior on JavaScript is *implementation-dependent*, the ISO8601 format was recently added to the ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification, but this is not yet supported by all implementations.

I would recommend you to parse it manually, for example:

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]);
}

parseDate('2011-01-03'); // Mon Jan 03 2011 00:00:00
```

Basically the above function matches each date part and uses the Date constructor, to build a date object, note that the *months* argument needs to be 0-based *(0=Jan, 1=Feb,...11=Dec)*.

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution I tried
Download date.js from http://datejs.com/
Include in your file

then
 var date = Date.parse('1970-01-12 00:00:00');
 var formattedDate = date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd');

Answer (score 1):

While @CMS's solution is probably superior, I found that using `Date.parse('2011-01-13')` is also a quick, working solution.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in Safari (5.1.3), I'm just getting `NaN` as the return value.

Comment: Right. `Date.parse` seems to be implementation specific.

Answer (score 0):

csnover has some progressive ISO 8601 Date enhancement code available on GitHub:
https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601/blob/master/iso8601.js

Including his code should provide a temporary fix while the Safari team work toward a more complete ES5 implementation.