# javascript date variable formatting - chrome vs safari

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, vimeo

I'm querying vimeo's API to get the uploaded date of my videos. I'm wondering why this works in chrome, but not safari, and what the proper way to create a time stamp for this video is:

```
  var vimeoDate = videos[i].upload_date;
  var vidDate = new Date(videos[i].upload_date);
  var vidTime = vidDate.getTime();

  console.log('vimeoDate: ' + vimeoDate + ', ' + vidDate + ', ' + vidTime);
  //returns: "vimeoDate: 2012-06-07 13:47:08, Invalid Date, NaN"
```

You can see a JSFiddle which returns invalid date here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nPSqL/

To simplify this, you can simply take this string: and run it in safari and it fails:

```
console.log(new Date('2013-01-02 13:33:51'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nPSqL/1/

Comment: try: console.log('vimeoDate: ' +(typeof vimeoDate) +', ' + vimeoDate + ', ' + vidDate + ', ' + vidTime);. Maybe it is actually a date.

Comment: typeof vimeoDate returns string

Comment: then it should work... are you serious, that all elements in your array returns string? give some more code or make a jsfiddle.net that behaves like this.

Comment: JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nPSqL/ - returns Invalid Date in safari

Comment: i've found something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622732/new-date-using-javascript-in-safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm

```
new Date('2012-06-07 13:47:08'); // works
```

therefore your given parameter must actually have type date. Because the console prints the date. If it's a date then you are trying to do something like that:

```
var date = new Date();
new Date(date); // doesn't work
```

And that doesn't work.

To check if your variable is of type date try this:

```
var isDate = function(date) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === "[object Date]";
};
```

**Ok, found solution**:
http://jsfiddle.net/nPSqL/2/

Got it from [new Date() using Javascript in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622732/new-date-using-javascript-in-safari)