# What "implementation dependent" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I think that "implementation dependent" is implementation(in javascript) depend on something.
Could you tell me What something is depended??

Thank you kindly.

p.s. if my writing in English too bad,I'm so sorry.

**Update** My question is about Property enumeration order.I forget to tell you.I'm Sorry.

Comment: I do not understand the question, can you explain yourself a little more?

Comment: an example of implementation dependcy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622732/new-date-using-javascript-in-safari

Comment: @JustinBicknell My question is about Property enumeration order.

Comment: okay, so in that case you can't depend on any specific property enumeration order.  Does that answer your question?  See Ted Hopp's comment to icktoofay's answer

Comment: @JustinBicknell ,Ok I will try to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript (or ECMAScript, to be more precise) is defined by a standard. Implementations, like V8, JavaScriptCore, and JScript… well, implement that standard. If some functionality is implementation-dependent, then it might only work the same way in that implementation and work differently in other implementations.

Comment: A good example is the order in which object properties are iterated in a `for..in` statement (or even whether the order is the same every time the statement is executed for the same object). This behavior is unspecified by the language.

Comment: Another is [`Date.prototype.toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2), where the returned string is `implementation-dependent, but [is] intended to represent the Date in the current time zone in a convenient, human-readable form`.

Comment: I get it!!! Thanks for your help. I'm late because I try to understand(and write English). Web browser have javascript implementation differently,haven't??