# Javascript Date plus 1 day

Tags: javascript, date

Here's my code:

```
function getRightMonth(month) {
  var monthArr = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
  return monthArr[month];
}   

var  setTomorrowDate = function(dtString){
    if(!dtString) return;
    var tm = new Date(dtString);
    tm.setDate(tm.getDate() + 1);
    var y = tm.getFullYear(),
        m = getRightMonth(tm.getMonth()),
        d = tm.getDate(),
        nd = (d < 10) ? "0" + d : d;          
    return y + "-" + m + "-" + nd;      
};

document.write(setTomorrowDate("2013-05-16"));
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/execuw/5/watch)

It simply takes a date string, sets a date and adds a day to it.
MY problem is that when I'm in Windows, it adds the one day, but if I'm in Mac it doesn't.

Comment: You mean in safari? Then this has been asked and anwered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622732/new-date-using-javascript-in-safari

Comment: In mac ,specify which browser you are using

Comment: Works fine on my Mac, both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Please try to debug your code, every browser has a developer tool where you can see the error or try to set a breakpoint and identify where exactly it doesn't work. http://wickedlysmart.com/hfhtml5/devtools.html For most browsers it opens by pressing F12 for FireFox I recommend installing the Firebug plugin.

Comment: I suggest trying out a library like Date.js or Moment.js for date-handling work. It'll make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of unsupportted date string in safari. I think this link will help you 
[Invalid date in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310953/invalid-date-in-safari)