# Polyfill for new Date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

In chromium:

```
new Date("10.10.2010")
// Sun Oct 10 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (EEST)
```

In firefox:

```
new Date("10.10.2010")
// Invalid Date
```

How i can polyfill this constructor in Firefox and IE? Maybe i should use other approach?

Comment: You should use another approach.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622732/new-date-using-javascript-in-safari